# Getting Website Category Against Keywords Using Google Search API

Tags: api, search

As the question suggest, does the Google Custom Search API have function to return category (music, entertainment, news, gaming, etc) based on input keywords?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adwords Keyword Planner tool or display plannertool for getting related ideas of keywords.